# Why are Java functions able to return local arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, c, return, stack

Just something I noticed: In C, for example, if you have a local array inside a function

```
*int returnArr() {
    int arr[5] = {0};
    return arr;
}
```

Obviously this will not compile. C will tell you that you're trying to return a local variable. Yet in Java, the same can be done...

```
int[] returnArr() {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    return arr;
}
```

and it causes no problems? Why is this? Why can Java do it but C can't?

Comment: Java has a garbage collector and stores nothing but primitives on the stack. Everything else goes into the heap.

Comment: @khelwood **C++** has a `new` operator but **C** doesn't!

Comment: “obviously this will not compile” — But it *does* compile (apart from the typo in the function return type).

Comment: @KonradRudolph it will cause a segmentation fault

Comment: @Jules If you’re lucky, yes. But it does that at *runtime*.

Comment: @AdrianMole D'oh.

Comment: C and Java are *completely* different languages with different rules and behavior; you shouldn’t be surprised if they don’t work the same.

Answer (score 6):

The two code snippets you show aren't *really* equivalent. In Java, [all arrays are dynamically allocated (on the heap)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/), rather than being created as 'function local' (on the stack).

The C code most nearly equivalent to your Java code would be to use either the `malloc()` or `calloc()` function (the latter to incorporate your `= {0}` initialization).

Thus, the following would be fine (but you would have to 'manually' release the memory using `free()` at some point, to emulate the Garbage Collector that Java has):

```c
int *returnArr() {
    int* arr = calloc(5, sizeof(int)); // "calloc" initializes to zero
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: oh I did not know that all arrays in Java were stored on the heap. I assumed an int[] array would just store on the stack as the same syntax would do in C. Thank you.